# How to determine the source of an import?

Tags: python, class, import

Forgive my ignorance here. I don't read Python well and I can't write it at all.

I'm trying to audit a python project for CVE-2013-1445. I believe found a source file that might need attention (among other opportunities for improvement). The file is [util.py](https://github.com/openstack/keystone/blob/master/keystone/openstack/common/crypto/utils.py), and it has the line:

```
import base64

from Crypto.Hash import HMAC
from Crypto import Random
...
```

When I look at the [Python crypto docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/crypto.html), I don't see mention of a `Random` class. Only `hashlib` and `hmac`:

```
The modules described in this chapter implement various algorithms of a
cryptographic nature. They are available at the discretion of the
installation. On Unix systems, the crypt module may also be available.
Here’s an overview:

    15.1. hashlib — Secure hashes and message digests
    15.2. hmac — Keyed-Hashing for Message Authentication

...
```

Where precisely is `Random` coming from? Is it native or third party?

Or should my question be, where is `Crypto` coming from? If `Crypto` its third party, how do I determine how/where third party libraries and classes are included (versus native libraries and classes)?

For completeness, I tried to understand Python's Scopes and Namespaces, but it makes no sense to me at the moment (as this question probably demonstrates). For example, there is no obvious Scope or Namespace for `Crypto` or `Random` (other than `Random` is part of `Crypto`).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Crypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) is not a standard library module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Crypto` is not part of any standard Python distribution.  That's why the Python docs don't mention it ;-)  You can download the source here:

https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/

Comment: Thank Tim. What determines when I should look for Python's native libraries, and when I should look outside of Python for other libraries?

Comment: @noloader: years of experience ;-)  Anyone can put any `.py` files they want anywhere they want to put them. *Conventions* exist on various platforms for where external Python packages "should be" placed, but such conventions vary by platform.  A `site-packages` directory under the Python directory is common.

Comment: Thanks Tim. So I'm clear: taking from Kevin's dump, `site-packages` is third parties? If so, where are the native packages stored?

Comment: Thanks again Time. I looked at https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto and the stuff provided in `src`. I did not see a `Random` class. Does the mean `Random` is neither native nor pycrypto? If so, where should I look?

Comment: `Random` is a package, [here](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/tree/master/lib/Crypto/Random).  Standard packages are stored in a variety of places, depending on platform conventions, but generally under a directory with a name starting with "python" too.  I suggest you download Python and install it yourself on the kinds of platforms you're interested in ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking where the file is stored?  Modules have an attribute named `__file__` which lists the path the module on disk.

```
>>> from Crypto import Random
>>> Random.__file__
'/home/ubuntu/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.pyc'
```

(In my case, PyCrypto is installed in a a virtualenv in my home dir)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I can't tell what is built-in, and what is external.  My question was similar to (and forgive the C/C++ alliteration), how do I know if Random is `Python::Crypto::Random`, or if its `Vendor::Crypto::Random`.

Comment: Yeah `site-packages` is generally third party modules.